# Can pydub don't lead to memory error when audio segment big file?

Tags: python, audio, segment, pydub

I got memory error every time when the file is big (a movie's length). Is there any way to handle big file audio segment?

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("vanilla_sky.mp3")
```

> ```
> File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 423, in from_mp3
> return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3')
> File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 412, in from_file
> obj = cls._from_safe_wav(output)
> File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 445, in _from_safe_wav
> return cls(data=file)
> File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 130, in __init__
> data = data if isinstance(data, basestring) else data.read()
> MemoryError
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In short, no — a pydub `AudioSegment` represents the audio itself (and contains the audio data).

There's been some discussion about adding a streaming version of `AudioSegment` to help with these memory issues, but that work hasn't been done yet (though I don't know of anyone specifically who is planning to tackle it).

#### Workarounds

If you just want to convert the audio, you can [turn on logging](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#debugging) and copy down the specific ffmpeg command you need to do the conversion. The logging output will show a subprocess call that you can use immediately in python code:

```
>>> import logging

>>> l = logging.getLogger("pydub.converter")
>>> l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

>>> AudioSegment.from_file("./vanilla_sky.mp3")
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', '/var/folders/71/42k8g72x4pq09tfp920d033r0000gn/T/tmpeZTgMy', '-vn', '-f', 'wav', '/var/folders/71/42k8g72x4pq09tfp920d033r0000gn/T/tmpK5aLcZ'])
```

(the first `/var/…` file is a copy of the input file, the second one is the output file, which is loaded into an `AudioSegment` after the conversion is done)

Comment: I solved this error by using 64-bit python interpreter... Anyway, thx for your answer.

Comment: @LeoHsieh interesting… I hadn't considered that potential problem